# Hideable arrays in PHP (dropdown)

Tags: php, arrays

I'll try to be brief and clear.

I don't know much PHP. I have an array that just looks too long:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4y11.jpg (can't post images yet, so please click)

As you can see, there are 7 options, and it looks ugly and long.

I would like to separate them into hideable sectors. Like:

3 first options [click here to dropdown options]
4 latest options [click here to dropdown options]

Instead of

Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
Option 4
Option 5
Option 6
Option 7

You know?

If someone could give me a light on this matter, I would be deeply grateful:

It's basically 7 copy and pastes like this:

```
    $url_bgcolor =  get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/admin/images/bgcolor/';
    $options[] = array( "name" => "Cor da letra do titulo da pagina",
                        "desc" => "Selecione a cor secundária do seu website.",
                        "id" => $shortname."_style2",
                        "std" => "",
                        "type" => "images",
                        "options" => array(
                                'default2.css' => $url_bgcolor . 'dark.png',
                                'black2.css' => $url_bgcolor . 'black.png',
                                'green2.css' => $url_bgcolor . 'green.png',
                                'blue2.css' => $url_bgcolor . 'blue.png',
                                'purple2.css' => $url_bgcolor . 'purple.png',
                                'orange2.css' => $url_bgcolor . 'orange.png',
                                'red2.css' => $url_bgcolor . 'red.png'
                ));
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to `hide/show` elements on your page, you need to use a client-side script like javascript. Here is a simple javascript function to toggle between `showing` and `hiding` your arrays.

In the `<head>` of you html add the following script/function-

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function toggleView(aid, id, text) {
    var divView = document.getElementById(id);
    var anchor = document.getElementByID(aid);

   if (divView.style.display != "block") {
       divView.style.display = "block";
       anchor.innerHTML = "click here to hide " + text + " options";
   } else {
      divView.style.display = "none";
      anchor.innerHTML = "click here to show " + text + " options";
   }
}
</script>
```

Then in your `<body>` you would create an `<a>` anchor, and a `<div>`

Your anchor tag and div would then look like this:

```
<a id="toggle3" onclick="toggleView('toggle3', 'options3', 'first 3')">click here to show first 3 options</a>
<div id="options3" style="display: none">
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
</div>

<a id="toggle4" onclick="toggleView('toggle4', 'options4', 'last 4')">click here to show last 4 options</a>
<div id="options4" style="display: none">
Option 4
Option 5
Option 6
Option 7
</div>
```

---

**EDITED 11/30**

Here is how I would do it -

**Javascript**
On line #438 of `admin-interface.php`, before the `<?php }` add the javascript `function()`

```
    <?php  
    //Hide/Show Image Groups  
    ?>  
<script type="text/javascript">   
function toggleView(aid, id, text) {  
    var divView = document.getElementById(id);  
    var anchor = document.getElementByID(aid);  

if (divView.style.display != "block") {
   divView.style.display = "block";
   anchor.innerHTML = "click here to hide " + text + " options";
} else {
  divView.style.display = "none";
  anchor.innerHTML = "click here to show " + text + " options";
}
}
</script>
```

**Anchor/DIV**
On line #603 of `admin-interface.php`, before the `//$output .= '<div class="section ...` add the `anchors` and `<div>`'s
*note:* if you have already added the javascript `function()` above, it might be line #621 instead of #603

```
if ($value['type'] == "images" && $counter == 1)
{$output .= '<a id="toggle3" onclick="toggleView(\'toggle3\', \'options3\', \'first 3\')">click here to show first 3 options</a>'."\n" . '<div id="options3" style="display: none">'."\n";}
if ($value['type'] == "images" && $counter == 4)
{$output .= '<a id="toggle4" onclick="toggleView(\'toggle4\', \'options4\', \'last 4\')">click here to show last 4 options</a>'."\n" . '<div id="options4" style="display: none">'."\n";}
```

On line #957 of `admin-interface.php`, before the `}$output .= '</div>';return array($output,$menu);` on #958-960, add the `</div>` closing tag
*note:* if you have already added the javascript `function()` and the `anchors` and `<div>`'s above, it might be line #979 instead of #957

```
if ($value['type'] == "images" && ($counter == 1 || $counter == 4))
{$output .= '</div>'."\n";}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer
I'm editing a wordpress theme, so it's in PHP.

The <head> file I think I've managed, by adding it to header.php

But the body part, it's more complicated because it's inside a PHP file, a php function... Should I use echo '<a id [etc] ' ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `echo "<a id=....>";`, which I have added as an example, or you can close out of php then start php again - `?><a id=...><?php ..`.

Comment: So, it isn't workign...

When I add echo "", it appears above the <head> tag, 'cause I think $options is some kind of function that is called somewhere else, and the content are arrays, you know?

Here's the full file:

http://www.mediafire.com/?qxfeiay872e2i3a

Comment: That file just sets up the `$option` array. What is your script that echo's the array? It should be something like `foreach($color as $option){echo $color['name'] ... $color['options'] ...`

Comment: i'll search, edit in a few -- Edit -- I'm almost sure that this is the one: http://www.mediafire.com/?38z7vmou7yv7j9z

Comment: I have added an edited answer above. It 'attempts' to provide line #'s of where to put the code, but it may differ slightly based off your code editor.

Comment: Sean, thank you for your help, really :] you're saving my ass. I'm in a friend's house now, when I come back home I'll try and edit here.

Comment: Sean, I'm already shame for taking you so much time...

So, here's what I got so far:

By adding everything, I got this:
http://i46.tinypic.com/2n9c9hk.jpg

It doesn't show anything when I click though;

My full_file.php got very different since that time, you might want to take a look: http://www.mediafire.com/?w2m9h5w1clz7svt

If you wish, send me a e-mail at: lucasb@executiva.art.br then I reply you with a Teamviewer ID and password so you can take a look. What do you think? Too much trouble? :S THANKS for your time so far!!!